# Custom Date and Time Input with date of "Today" adding one day for a Restaurant

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am currently a student and I would like to get some help for a website I am creating.This is what I would like to make it look like.

[image]
So what I am trying would be this, today is the 30th Oct. 18, adding 1 Day, like shown on the form and having the current time, which is not the hard part, I am just unsure about the date and I can't find the right solution on the internet.

If anybody could help, that would be great.

Thank you before hand.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit] the question and add the relevant parts of your code into it, because without that we cannot help. Also please see **[ask]**.

Comment: Hi @peter, I have not added any image, since I am on holidays and I have left my Laptop at home, but I was trying to find a solution anyways, but since I have not found any online, I decided to ask the question. If that will be a problem, I will delete post, that is no problem, I just thought that somebody could help me.